# Sending shell command in function argument not working

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, command

I am working on a shell script where I have requirement that I need to run all my command inside from a function.
I have written below code in my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

function RUN_CMD() 
{
    CMD=${*}
    echo "Command launched: \"${CMD}\"."
    ($*)
    RETVAL=$?

    if [ $RETVAL = 0 ] ; then
        echo "Command successful: \"${CMD}\"."
    else
        echo "Command failed with RC=${RETVAL}: \"${CMD}\"."
    fi
    return $RETVAL
}
_cmd="tr -d 'the' < file.txt > file.new"
RUN_CMD "$_cmd"
```

When executing this code I am getting below error.

```
tr: extra operand ‘<’
Try 'tr --help' for more information.
Command failed with RC=1: "tr -d 'the' < file.txt > file.new".
```

I don't what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle redirections (pipes, etc.) when you run `$*` or `$@` in a function this way. The redirection operators `<` and `>` get passed to `tr` as arguments. You need to use redirection when calling the function:

```
_cmd="tr -d the"
RUN_CMD "$_cmd" < file.txt > file.new
```

Or use `eval`:

```
_cmd="tr -d 'the' < file.txt > file.new"
eval $_cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

you could run your command in a subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash

function RUN_CMD() 
{
    OUT=$(/bin/bash -c "$1")
    RETVAL=$?
    echo "Command launched: \"$1\"."
    if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo "Command successful: \"$1\", \"OUT=${OUT}\""
    else
        echo "Command failed with RC=${RETVAL}: \"$1\", \"OUT=${OUT}\""
    fi
    return $RETVAL
}
_cmd="tr -d 't' < file.txt > file.out"
RUN_CMD "$_cmd"
```

Best,
  Julian